# Join same table without conditions - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table that has records

```
id_queue | user_id | id_book | status
```

```
   69    |    5    |    4    |   1
```

```
   133   |    3    |    4    |   2
```

```
   142   |    1    |    4    |   0
```

I want a query that will give me this result

```
id_queue | id_queue
```

```
   69    |    142
```

```
   133   |    null
```

I've tried something like this

```
SELECT s1.`id_queue`,s2.`id_queue` FROM `second` as s1
LEFT JOIN `second` as s2 ON s2.`book_id`=4 AND s2.`status` IN (0)
WHERE s1.`book_id`=4 AND s1.`status` IN (1,2,4)
```

but it keeps bringing me this result.

```
id_queue | id_queue
```

```
   69    |    142
```

```
   133   |    142
```

I think this is because I don't have anything identical for conditions. What can I do?

Comment: is there a reason behind placing `69` and `133` in a column different from `142` and `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are joining on the `book_id` not the status, so you will always have a matching row.

If you want to hide the second instance of the second `id_queue` then you can use user defined variables:

```
select Queue1,
  case when seq = 1 then queue2 else null end Queue2
from
(
  select 
    Queue1,
    Queue2,
    @row:=(case when @prev=Queue2 then @row else 0 end) +1 as Seq,
    @prev:=Queue2 
  from
  (
    SELECT 
      s1.`id_queue` Queue1,
      s2.`id_queue` Queue2
    FROM `second` as s1
    LEFT JOIN `second` as s2 
      ON s1.`id_book` = s2.`id_book`
      AND s2.`status` = 0
    WHERE s1.`id_book`=4 
      AND s1.`status` IN (1,2,4)
  ) src, (SELECT @row:=0, @prev:=null) r
  order by Queue1, Queue2
) s1
order by Queue1, Queue2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a212d/34)

The result is:

```
| QUEUE1 | QUEUE2 |
-------------------
|     69 |    142 |
|    133 | (null) |
```

Comment: Thanks this worked just fine!!!! I need to learn more about cases and user defined variable!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens because you're setting multiple values of the same column on multiple columns... this way it may end up seeming as multiple rows.

And it seems that if you put a "DISTINCT" command just after the select it wouldn't cause any value to disappear, as it would check if all the columns of the row were the same to another one.

But you can always try to put the DISTINCT just before the value you don't want to repeat and check if it works.

Wish I could help you more.

Example:

```
    SELECT s1.`id_queue`, DISTINCT (s2.`id_queue`)
    FROM `second` as s1
    LEFT JOIN `second` as s2 ON s2.`book_id`=4 AND s2.`status` IN (0)
    WHERE s1.`book_id`=4 AND s1.`status` IN (1,2,4)
```